# “ group by” doesn't use index when using “where in” in database

Tags: sql, database, kingbase

there is a combination index like  index_3 (phone,age);
the DBMS is kingbase which probably developed base on postgresql.
the code is behind

```
explain 
select age from app_user 
where phone in ('18595910055','18105156925','18634791357') 
group by age having count(age) >= 3;
```

the result shows the temporary is used and the key "phone" is also 63,so that means index didn't use the key "age".
the question is why I still got the same result even I remove "having" from my code?

Comment: I'm not surprised that your query as above does not use the index, as count queries are notorious for not being sargable.  But I don't have an explanation as to why no index is used upon removing the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Using the index looks beneficial in both cases on first glance, but it may not be the case. How many rows are in the table? If there are a million rows, then I'd be surprised that the index is not used. If there are just hundred rows, then a sequential full table scan may still be faster than scanning an index.

Comment: Please add more information like total count of `app_user` and the output of `explain`!